# Number of walks from $u$ to $v$ in $X$ with length $r$ is $(A^r)_{uv}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, graph-theory

Currently I am reading [Algebraic Graph Theory](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387952413) by Godsil and Royle.
In Chapter $8,$ page $165$, the authors stated the following lemma.

> **Lemma** $8.1.2$ 
>    Let $X$ be a directed graph with adjacency matrix $A.$  The number of walks from $u$ to $v$ in $X$ with length $r$ is $(A^r)_{uv}.$

The authors stated that the lemma can be proven by using induction on $r.$
Below is my attempt:

My attempt:

Suppose that $r=1.$ 
Note that a walk of length $r=1$ from $u$ to $v$ is just an edge connecting $u$ and $v.$
By definition of adjacency matrix $A,$ the number of walks from $u$ to $v$ of length $r=1$ is $(A)_{uv}.$

Suppose that the statement holds for $r.$
Now, we want to prove that it holds for $r+1.$
Fix two vertices $u$ and $v$ of $X.$
Let 
$$W = \{ w\in X: \text{ there exists a walk of length }r \text{ from }u \text{ to }w \}.$$
Fix $w\in W.$
Then a walk from $u$ to $v$ of length $r+1$ is a walk from $u$ to $w$ and walk of length $1$ from $w$ to $v.$
By inductive hypothesis, the number of walks from $u$ to $v$ of length $r+1$ is 
$$\sum_{w\in W} (A^r)_{uw} A_{wv} = (A^{r+1})_{uv}.$$
Therefore, the statement holds for $r+1.$

Hence, by induction, the statement holds for any positive integer $r.$

Is my proof correct?